# Importing firebase cloud functions in a React project

Tags: reactjs, firebase, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am building a react app (this part might be inconsequential) and have a server cloud function built:

```
exports.myFunction = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  ...
}
```

I know that calling this in my client would normally consist of calling

```
firebase.functions().httpsCallable('myFunction');
```

And I have tried this in a separate project, and it works.  However, that was using a script tag to import the functions module in my `index.html`:

```
<script src="/__/firebase/7.7.9/firebase-functions.js"></script>
```

but in my current project, my modules are imported in my `firebase.js` source:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: ...
  ...
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app);
```

I wasn't able to find any example code for importing functions this way, and everything I have tried has failed.

How can I import `functions` so that I can invoke the above method?  Even better, how could I figure this out on my own? (I have been relying on example code so far).  I assume that these are referencing the NPM packages I have `npm install`'ed (or in my case, `yarn add`'ed), but I don't immediately see where the code is actually being referenced so I can work this out on my own.

Comment: let me know if below recommendation was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far what I have understood from you question it is regarding how can firebase cloud function module be imported while using a react app which is calling a HTTPS callable function at the client side.You can use any library or built-in command of your environment to call a [HTTPS function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#invoke_an_http_function).

I would recommend you to try the following to your imports and see if that works.
`import { getFunctions, httpsCallable } from "firebase/functions";`
OR
`import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'; import React from 'react'; import { renderToString } from 'react-dom/server'; import App from './src/App';`

Check the below for similar implementation examples to better understand this and implement according to your requirements.

- [How to call Firebase function from within react component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58895691/how-do-i-call-firebase-functions-from-within-a-react-component/58895936#58895936)
- [Call Firebase HTTPS callable function in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252506/call-firebase-https-callable-cloud-functions-in-react)
- [Implement callable function in react app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487770/implement-callable-cloud-functions-in-firebase-client-app?rq=1)
- [Firebase callable function CORS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50278537/firebase-callable-function-cors)